# How can I implement this jQuery time picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, timepicker

I have a text box for the user to insert the time into.

It's ID is tarTime, so I am guessing that I have to start it `$("input#tarTime").`

I need it to be able to have just the minute and second slider.

I am using this website: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

I know a bit of jQuery, but I don't seem to be able to get this to work, and I think I have included all the right files.

I would be very grateful of any suggestions, or a bit of code of how I can implement this, thank you in advance :)

Comment: I might be mistaken but an id is a unique value on the DOM.  Why would you need to do input#tarTime when #tarTime would suffice?

Comment: Also, is the date picker opening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you're aware, but it might be worth noting that Trent Richardson's Timepicker is an addon to jQuery UI's datepicker.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

You'll need to make sure that you have it included as well.

Then, your syntax is simply:

`$('#tarTime').timepicker({});`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use:

```
$('#tarTime').timepicker({});
```

On the examples page, you can see it is the third example

Comment: nah, I've tried that, and all the rest, doesn't seem to be working, not sure what Iv'e missed out :/

Comment: You must have a syntax error elsewhere; have you tried debugging with Firebug or checking your error console? Here is a simple [proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/ydTge/)